# ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have a problem :)

I wanted to run a docker-compose for the first time.

But he got it wrong

It is this one:
https://github.com/navilg/media-stack

Here is my error message:

```
root@ubuntu:~/docker-compose/media-stack# docker-compose --profile stack-2 up -d
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
'name' does not match any of the regexes: '^x-'
```

You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Here are my versions:

```
root@ubuntu:~/docker-compose/media-stack# docker version
Customer:
 Version: 20.10.16
 API version: 1.41
 Go version: go1.18.1
 Git commit: 20.10.16-0ubuntu1
 Built: Thu May 12 20:45:12 2022
 OS/Arch: linux/arm64
 Context: default
 Experimental: true

server:
 Engine:
  Version: 20.10.16
  API version: 1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version: go1.18.1
  Git commit: 20.10.16-0ubuntu1
  Built: Thu May 12 20:04:31 2022
  OS/Arch: linux/arm64
  Experimental: false
 containerd:
  Version: 1.6.4-0ubuntu1.1
  GitCommit:
 runc:
  Version: 1.1.2-0ubuntu1.1
  GitCommit:
 docker-init:
  Version: 0.19.0
  GitCommit:
root@ubuntu:~/docker-compose/media-stack# docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.3
CPython version: 3.10.7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022
```

I tried to change version on the docker-compose to version 1 or 2 and 3 but nothing works.

Here is the docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"
name: media-stack
services:
  vpn:
  ## Read https://github.com/qdm12/gluetun/wiki for details on configuring VPN for different service providers.
    profiles: ["vpn", "stack-2"]
    container_name: vpn
    image: qmcgaw/gluetun:v3.32
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER=${VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER:-nordvpn} # Valid values: nordvpn, expressvpn, protonvpn, surfshark or custom
      - OPENVPN_USER=${OPENVPN_USER:-""}
      - OPENVPN_PASSWORD=${OPENVPN_PASSWORD:-""}

      ## For list of server regions and countries, visit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qdm12/gluetun/master/internal/storage/servers.json

      ## SERVER_REGIONS is required for NordVPN and Surfshark VPN. Comment SERVER_COUNTRIES if SERVER_REGIONS is used.
      - SERVER_REGIONS=${SERVER_REGIONS:-Switzerland}

      ## SERVER_COUNTRIES is required for ExpressVPN and ProtonVPN. Comment SERVER_REGIONS if SERVER_COUNTRIES is used.
      # - SERVER_COUNTRIES=${SERVER_COUNTRIES:-Netherlands}
      # - FREE_ONLY=on  # Valid with protonvpn only. on if using free service provided by protonvpn

      ## Enable below if VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER=custom
      # - VPN_TYPE=openvpn # or wireguard.

      ## If VPN_TYPE is openvpn
      # - OPENVPN_CUSTOM_CONFIG=/gluetun/custom.conf

      ## If VPN_TYPE is wireguard. Replace below env variables as required.
      # - VPN_ENDPOINT_IP=1.2.3.4                                               # Replace with your wg endpoint ip or domain
      # - VPN_ENDPOINT_PORT=51820                                               # Replace with wg server port
      # - WIREGUARD_PUBLIC_KEY=wAUaJMhAq3NFutLHIdF8AN0B5WG8RndfQKLPTEDHal0=     # Replace with your wg public key
      # - WIREGUARD_PRIVATE_KEY=wOEI9rqqbDwnN8/Bpp22sVz48T71vJ4fYmFWujulwUU=    # Replace with your wg client private key
      # - WIREGUARD_PRESHARED_KEY=xOEI9rqqbDwnN8/Bpp22sVz48T71vJ4fYmFWujulwUU=  # Replaced with your wg pre-shared key
      # - WIREGUARD_ADDRESSES="10.64.222.21/32"                                 # Replace with wg address

    ## Enable volume if custom VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER is used
    # volumes:
      # - /yourpath/yourconfig.conf:/gluetun/config.conf:ro

    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      # qbittorrent ports
      - 5080:5080
      - 6881:6881
      - 6881:6881/udp
      # prowlarr ports
      - 9696:9696
      # Transmission ports. Uncomment below if Transmission is used with VPN
      # - 9091:9091
      # - 51413:51413
      # - 51413:51413/udp
    restart: "unless-stopped"
  transmission:
    profiles: ["tx", "stack-1"]
    container_name: transmission
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/transmission:3.00-r6
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    # network_mode: service:vpn # Uncomment this line if vpn is enabled
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=UTC
      - USER=admin
      - PASS=nimdatx

    ## Comment below ports if VPN is enabled.
    ports:
      - 9091:9091
      - 51413:51413
      - 51413:51413/udp
    volumes:
      - tx-config:/config
      - torrent-downloads:/downloads
      - tx-watch:/watch
    restart: "unless-stopped"

  ## Default credentials - Username: admin password: adminadmin ##
  ## Change password after install from UI --> Tools --> Options --> WebUI ##
  qbittorrent:
    container_name: qbittorrent
    profiles: ["qbt", "stack-2"]
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/qbittorrent:4.5.0
    # Comment this if vpn is disabled
    depends_on:
      - vpn
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    network_mode: service:vpn # Comment this line if vpn is disabled
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=UTC
      - WEBUI_PORT=5080
    volumes:
      - qbittorrent-config:/config
      - torrent-downloads:/downloads

    ## Uncomment below ports if VPN is disabled.
    # ports:
    #   - 5080:5080
    #   - 6881:6881
    #   - 6881:6881/udp
    restart: "unless-stopped"
  radarr:
    profiles: ["base", "radarr", "stack-1", "stack-2"]
    container_name: radarr
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/radarr:4.2.4
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=UTC
    ports:
      - 7878:7878
    volumes:
      - radarr-config:/config
      - torrent-downloads:/downloads
    restart: "unless-stopped"

  sonarr:
    profiles: ["base", "sonarr", "stack-1", "stack-2"]
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/sonarr:develop-version-4.0.0.269
    container_name: sonarr
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=UTC
    volumes:
      - sonarr-config:/config
      - torrent-downloads:/downloads
    ports:
      - 8989:8989
    restart: unless-stopped

  jackett:
    profiles: ["jackett", "stack-1"]
    container_name: jackett
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/jackett:v0.20.2309
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=UTC
    volumes:
      - jackett-config:/config
      - jackett-blackhole:/downloads
    ports:
      - 9117:9117
    restart: unless-stopped

  prowlarr:
    profiles: ["prowlarr", "stack-2"]
    container_name: prowlarr
    image: linuxserver/prowlarr:0.4.9-develop
    # Comment this if vpn is disabled
    depends_on:
      - vpn
    network_mode: service:vpn # Comment this line if vpn is disabled
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=UTC
    volumes:
      - prowlarr-config:/config
    ## Uncomment below ports if VPN is disabled.
    # ports:
    #   - 9696:9696
    restart: unless-stopped

  jellyfin:
    profiles: ["base", "jelly", "stack-1", "stack-2"]
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/jellyfin:10.8.8
    container_name: jellyfin
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=UTC
    volumes:
      - jellyfin-config:/config
      - torrent-downloads:/data
  # devices:
   #  - /dev/videoN:/dev/videoN # Mount GPU device
    ports:
      - 8096:8096
      - 7359:7359/udp
      - 8920:8920
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  torrent-downloads:
  radarr-config:
  sonarr-config:
  jackett-config:
  jackett-blackhole:
  prowlarr-config:
  jellyfin-config:
  qbittorrent-config:
  tx-config:
  tx-watch:

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
```

Have you ever seen this problem?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: That could happen if you were running a version-1 Compose file (without `version:` or `services:` top-level items) against the newer Docker-plugin version of Compose.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Including the actual `docker-compose.yml` file directly in the question will be much more informative than the `docker version` output.

Comment: Remove `name: media-stack` in the second line and I think it will work

Comment: Wow it was that simple!

I searched everywhere

Thank you very much it works again